# How can I launch Firefox developer tools programmatically?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu9Ju.png

In particular, I'm interested in creating a keybinding to the eyedropper tool. *If possible* I'd like to see this done in the context of an extension, whether by the SDK or something like a call to `gBrowser`.

**Edit**

I found a solution by filtering for "command" in the DOM inspector. `openEyedropper()` works perfectly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9OtS.png

Comment: Nice job finding solution :) Dom Insepctor is the way to go :) Post it as solution when you are allowed to and ill up vote. You deserve it great job! Do you have element inspector addon? with it you can shift + right click anything and it will open i tin dom inspector :) https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/element-inspector/

Comment: Hey, thanks. I'm already all over that inspector add-on.

Comment: Cool man good job finding it :)

Comment: I hope you can help me with another problem. I'm making the same effort as before only I want to control the bookmarks bar (hide, show). The DOM points me to a command `onViewToolbarCommand(event)`, however I don't know what sort of event it expects (or how to simulate it at that). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Ah! Not a minute later and I've found it digging around browser.js. `CustomizableUI.setToolbarVisibility("PersonalToolbar", isVisible)` does it.

Comment: Nice job man! I didn't even know that. Thanks for sharing it. It's better to ask a seperate question for different subject :)